# How to extract human voice from cluttered signal?

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, voice, array-signal-processing

I have a signal which has human speech, background voice and noise as it can be seen in below figure.[image]

I have calculated its power spectral density (PSD) using many different methods which can be seen in below figure.[image]

As far as I guess, peak regions which are spotted in red rectangle on the PSD belong to harmonics of the human speech. In addition, out of these harmonics represent noise, although they carry a little meaningful information of human speech. I am wondering how I can extract the human voice as well-filtered as possible from this cluttered signal.

Should I filter harmonics or out of harmonics? Should I use a notch filter or a band-pass filter? Which filter should be chosen to obtain high quality human voice?

Comment: Please provide URL to download the signal, e.g. [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [Drive](https://drive.google.com/), [ufile](https://ufile.io/)

Comment: Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V9L1GPKxD1g0Y4I__IwHM6UC1hnAn-rB?usp=sharing) to access the .wav file. @OverLordGoldDragon